# Document storage in Azure ADB2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage

I am looking to create a form aadb2c with the possibility to insert a document that will be linked to the account created.

I have searched but for now I can not find a solution.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD B2C is an Customer Identity and Access Management as a service solution. Do not use it to store documents. There are bunch of other services you can use to store documents ([Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-existing-database), [Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction), [Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search), etc.).

You cannot and you shall not store documents in Azure AD.